# Firebase - Deep Query orderByChild with equalTo

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to grab every project by the members within them -- I've created a sample datastructure though the actual structure is much larger (as in it would be difficult to restructure the database).

Here is my query:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL + '/chat/meta/project');

var email = 'kerry@email.com';

ref
    .orderByChild("email")
    .equalTo(email)
    .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    }
);
```

It is important to note that if I remove the `.equalTo(email)` that it returns all of the "projects", when it should only return 2 of them.

Here is the data in Firebase:

```
{
  "chat" : {
    "meta" : {
      "project" : {
        "-KAgjWOxjk80HIbNr68M" : {
          "name" : "Gman Branding",
          "url" : "http://localhost:3000/project/abc123fasd123cc/...",
          "date" : "2015-10-10T21:33:25.170Z",
          "member" : {
            "-KAgkD-2GVESwNwKP3fA" : {
              "email" : "abc@gman.com"
            },
            "-KAgkP3M4nug9Bjn-vY6" : {
              "email" : "def@gman.com"
            },
            "-KAgkP3OF0sUgc9x9p37" : {
              "email" : "ghi@gman.com"
            },
            "-KAgkaMyEOiXft6o-HbO" : {
              "email" : "kerry@email.com"
            }
          }
        },
        "-KAgl9xlPDU5T4072FgE" : {
          "-KAglqH9pxkhgC84_kAl" : {
            "name" : "YuDog",
            "url" : "http://localhost:3000/project/abc123fasd123cc/...",
            "date" : "2015-10-10T21:41:31.172Z"
          },
          "name" : "billing test 1",
          "url" : "http://localhost:3000/project/abc123fasd123cc/...",
          "date" : "2015-02-25T23:18:55.626Z",
          "dateNotifyUnread" : "2016-01-25T23:23:55.626Z",
          "member" : {
            "-KAglNsswyk66qUZNrTU" : {
              "email" : "kerry@email.com"
            }
          }
        },
        "-KAgltmLk2oOYhEDfwRL" : {
          "-KAgm1Jt5q53gzLm1GIh" : {
            "name" : "YuDog",
            "url" : "http://localhost:3000/project/abc123fasd123cc/...",
            "date" : "2015-10-10T21:41:31.172Z"
          },
          "name" : "YuDog",
          "url" : "http://localhost:3000/project/abc123fasd123cc/...",
          "date" : "2015-10-10T21:41:31.172Z",
          "member" : {
            "-KAgm1Jvss9AMZa1qDb7" : {
              "email" : "joe@yudog.com"
            }
          }
        },
        "-KAgluTcE_2dv00XDm1L" : {
          "-KAgm6ENmkpDiDG2lqZ4" : {
            "name" : "YuDog Landing Page",
            "url" : "http://localhost:3000/project/abc123fasd123cc/...",
            "date" : "2015-10-10T21:41:31.172Z"
          },
          "-KAgmBptbeInutRzNinm" : {
            "name" : "YuDog Landing Page",
            "url" : "http://localhost:3000/project/abc123fasd123cc/...",
            "date" : "2015-10-10T21:41:31.172Z"
          },
          "name" : "YuDog Landing Page",
          "url" : "http://localhost:3000/project/abc123fasd123cc/...",
          "date" : "2015-10-10T21:41:31.172Z",
          "member" : {
            "-KAgm6EQcvQg3oP-OnIF" : {
              "email" : "joe@yudog.com"
            },
            "-KAgmBpwoxPYGXS9fLZ9" : {
              "email" : "joe@yudog.com"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've looked at 8-10 other links on SO but haven't found any that solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to create a data structure that matches your needs. In this case, you want to look up the projects for a user based on their email address. So we'll *add* a node that contains this mapping:

```
"projects_by_email": {
  "kerry@email,com": {
    "-KAgjWOxjk80HIbNr68M": true,
    "-KAgl9xlPDU5T4072FgE": true
  },
  "abc@gman,com": {
    "-KAgjWOxjk80HIbNr68M": true
  }
  ...
}
```

This is called denormalizing your data, although I often think of them as inverted indexes. I would probably keep the projects by uid, but the structure would be the same.

With a structure like this, you can get the list of projects for an email with a simple direct look up:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
var email = 'kerry@email.com';
ref.child('projects_by_email')
   .child(email)
   .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
       console.log(snapshot.key());
   }
);
```

Or if you then also want to "join" the projects themselves:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
var email = 'kerry@email.com';
ref.child('projects_by_email')
   .child(email)
   .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
       ref.child('project').child(snapshot.key()).once('value', function(projectSnapshot) {
           console.log(projectSnapshot.val());
       });
   }
);
```

This type of denormalizing is a normal part of NoSQL data modeling. The duplication may feel wasteful, but it is part of why NoSQL solution scale so well: none of the code above asks the database to consider all projects/all users. It's all directly accessing the correct nodes, which scales really well. So we're sacrificing storage space to gain improved performance/scalability; a typical space vs time trade-off.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the response, but I'm looking for a way to do it without modifying any of the structure

Comment: The only way to do that, is to add a deep index on each push ID. `"-KAgkD-2GVESwNwKP3fA"`, `"-KAgkP3M4nug9Bjn-vY6"`, etc. I doubt that is what you want either. In NoSQL you often model the data for the way you want to access it. For this and more see this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: It looks like email format is not allowed as key, I got this:  **First argument was an invalid path: "e.mail@mail.com". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"**

Comment: Yeah, I should've been more explicit: when using email addresses as keys, you should encode it. Typically devs change the `.` with a `,`, which handily is not allowed in email addreses.