# What is the suitable query for the following case?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is my database structure:
[image: Database snap]

I am trying to list all users with "locale" equal to "Cairo, Egypt" so I made the following query:

```
exports.calculateMatches = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
```

// Access users' profiles that are located in the locale of the requesting user

```
databaseRef.child("users").orderByChild("locale").equalTo(request.query.locale).once("value")
     .then(snap => {
       snap.forEach(profile => {
         console.log(profile);
       });
    });
 });
```

Note this function is deployed to firebase cloud functions and this is what I get in the logs:
[image: logs]

Comment: Instead of including screenshots of errors, it's more helpful to copy the text and place it directly in the question so that it can be searched more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS type functions require that you [send a response](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) to the client in order to terminate the function.  Without that, they will always time out, and the client will be waiting the whole time.

For example:

```
const databaseRef = admin.database().ref('')
exports.calculateMatches = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    databaseRef.child("users").orderByChild("locale").equalTo(request.query.locale).once("value")
    .then(snap => {
        const profiles = []
        snap.forEach(profile => {
            profiles.push(profile.val())
        });
        response.send(profiles)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        response.status(500).send(error)
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome now I get a decent view of JSON data but I get nothing. I tried to keep it to just orderByChild without the equalTo part but also got nothing ... something wrong with the query ?

Comment: /users doesn't have a child named "locale".  There's a couple extra levels of children in there.  You'll have to restructure your data to suit the kind of query you want to perform.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446695/firebase-deep-query-orderbychild-with-equalto